# dp.opt file isn't creating when using "create database"

Tags: mysql

my problem is that when i use mysql to create database it described that it should create db.opt file, but it doesn't. How to fix that, i'm using mysql mysql-8.0.32-winx64 portable version

1. I have tried to enable that option innodb_file_per_table=ON in my.cnf file;
2. Also, i have tried to enable server with that argument "--skip-opt", and also imported it in my.cnf;
   It seems that noone is faced that problem before and yeah i know that i doesn't really need that file it is just for my homework, by that file i should show that my databases have right CHARACTER SET and COLLATE.
   For all that i using comand line interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL 8.0 is working as designed. The `db.opt` file and other metadata files are no longer used, because this version of MySQL implements metadata in a different way.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/data-dictionary-file-removal.html

> The metadata files listed below are removed from MySQL. Unless otherwise noted, data previously stored in metadata files is now stored in data dictionary tables.
>
> ...
>
> - `db.opt` files: Database configuration files. These files, one per database directory, contained database default character set attributes.

I have no idea what homework you would be doing that requires direct access to `db.opt`. That file is normally only used by internal code of MySQL 5. I've been using MySQL since 2001, but I've never had any need to read that file directly.

Comment: i appreciate your answer, thanks a lot